# Python Tkinter button freezes program after using hotkey

Tags: python, multithreading, tkinter

I am trying to build a simple auto clicker program which has start/stop buttons and a hotkey (using Tkinter and Pynput). Whenever I start the auto clicker using the start button, it works perfectly and I am able to stop it. However, when I start the auto clicker using the hotkey, I cannot stop it with the stop button as it freezes the entire program.

This is my main class for the GUI:

```py
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent
        self.parent.bind("<Destroy>", self.exit)

        self.clicker = Clicker(Button.left, 1)
        self.clicker.start()

        self.kb = Keyboard("<shift>+s", self.start_click)
        self.kb.start()

        btn_box = ttk.Combobox(self, values=BUTTONS, state="readonly")
        btn_box.current(0)
        btn_box.pack()

        start = tk.Button(self, text="Start", command=self.start_click)
        start.pack()

        stop = tk.Button(self, text="Stop", command=self.stop_click)
        stop.pack()

        exit = tk.Button(self, text="Exit", command=self.exit)
        exit.pack()


    def start_click(self):
        self.clicker.start_click()


    def stop_click(self):
        print("e")
        self.clicker.stop_click()


    def exit(self, event=None):
        self.clicker.exit()
        self.parent.quit()
```

And these are my Clicker and Keyboard classes:

```py
class Clicker(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, button, delay):
        super().__init__()

        self.button = button
        self.delay = delay

        self.running = False
        self.prog_running = True

        self.mouse = Controller()


    def start_click(self):
        print("start")
        self.running = True


    def stop_click(self):
        print("stop")
        self.running = False


    def exit(self):
        self.running = False
        self.prog_running = False


    def run(self):
        while self.prog_running:
            while self.running:
                self.mouse.click(self.button)
                time.sleep(self.delay)
            time.sleep(0.1)
```

```py
class Keyboard(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, keybind, command):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.hk = HotKey(HotKey.parse(keybind), command)


    def for_canonical(self, f):
        return lambda k: f(self.l.canonical(k))


    def run(self):
        with Listener(on_press=self.for_canonical(self.hk.press),
                      on_release=self.for_canonical(self.hk.release)) as self.l:
            self.l.join()
```

Does anyone know why it freezes when pressing the stop button after using the hotkey?

Comment: It works fine in my Windows 7.

Comment: I'm on windows 10 and it doesn't work for me.

Comment: It works fine on Windows 10 in my notebook as well.

Comment: I think I know why. Whenever I use the hotkey and hold the cursor inside the GUI, it doesn't freeze when I press stop. However, if I use the hotkey and move the cursor elsewhere, the above problem occurs. I have tried updating the root with `self.parent.update()` but the problem still persists.

Comment: I figured it out. It is the frame that I needed to update. I just added a `self.update` before the `stop_click` method in the main frame class and it works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I had issues when I used `self.quit()` instead of `self.destroy()` but most probably, that's not it with your case.

Adding the shortcut using `self.bind()` may be a solution,

For example:

```
#Importing the tkinter module
from tkinter import *
#Creating a window
root = Tk()
#Creating a label
txt = Label(root, text="Opened! But I'm closing, you know...").grid(row=1, column=1)
#Defining an action and binding it(root is the window's name)
def actionn(*args):
    root.destroy()
root.bind('<Shift-S>', actionn)
#Showing the window and the label
root.mainloop()
```

You can't bind shift like that, bind it with `self.parent.bind('<Shift-S>')`
I guess it freezes because the shortcut assigned doesn't work...

Comment: The thing is that I want to use the hotkeys even when the root is not focused. Binding like that only works when the GUI is in focus as far as I know. That's why I used the pynput module to take care of the hotkeys. Thanks for the answer though. :))